# SCIP Optimization Suite Installation: Vector Subscript Out of Range Error

Tags: boost, scip

I'm using Win10 and Visual Studio 2017. My SCIP Optimization Suite version is 8.0.3. I use CMake to compile to source code and is able to compile successfully:

[image]

However, when I tried to compile "queens" project, I got the following error:

[image]

Looks like SCIP is not working properly with boost. Do I need to add Boost lib to the visual studio somewhere?

Comment: You're using the latest SCIP and 3.5 year old Boost – maybe try updating the latter

Comment: @ildjarn I just tried the latest Boost version 1_82_0 and get same linkage issue. I suspect I might need to add Boost lib information to the project somewhere - either in visual studio project setting or cmake file.